# UWP and HockeyApp crash reporting: Crash reports are not meaningful at all

Tags: uwp, windows-10, crash-reports, hockeyapp, crash-log

I've integrated HockeyApp in my UWP application and put a NotImplementedException on a button click just for testing purpose.
What I'm seeing in hockey is the following

```
Exception Stack:
SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x68beef
SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x8255c6
SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x8d41b8
SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x89ccef
GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Helpers.WeakAction.Execute() in D:\GalaSoft\mydotnet\MVVMLight\source\GalaSoft.MvvmLight\GalaSoft.MvvmLight (PCL)\Helpers\WeakAction.cs:line 287
GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand.Execute(Object parameter) in D:\GalaSoft\mydotnet\MVVMLight\source\GalaSoft.MvvmLight\GalaSoft.MvvmLight (PCL)\Command\RelayCommand.cs:line 221
SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x6a7f41
SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x6a7eb3
McgInterop.McgHelpers.ThrowFailed(Int32 hr, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHnd) in f:\SVN\TestApp\ TestApp\obj\x86\Test\ilc\intermediate\ TestApp.McgInterop\Helpers.g.cs:line 8148
McgInterop.ComCallHelpers.ComCall__HRESULT($__ComObject __this, RuntimeTypeHandle __typeHnd, Int32 __targetIndex) in f:\SVN\ TestApp\ TestApp\obj\x86\Test\ilc\intermediate\ TestApp.McgInterop\SharedStubs.g.cs:line 9827
McgInterop.ForwardComSharedStubs.Proc_<System.__Canon>($__ComObject __this, Int32 __targetIndex) in f:\SVN\ TestApp\ TestApp\obj\x86\Test\ilc\intermediate\ TestApp.McgInterop\SharedStubs.g.cs:line 622
Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.IUnhandledError__Impl.StubClass.Propagate($__ComObject __this) in f:\SVN\ TestApp\ TestApp\obj\x86\Test\ilc\intermediate\ TestApp.McgInterop\ImplTypes.g.cs:line 105254
Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.UnhandledError.Propagate() in f:\SVN\ TestApp\ TestApp\obj\x86\Test\ilc\intermediate\ TestApp.McgInterop\SafeTypes.g.cs:line 44801
Microsoft.HockeyApp.Extensibility.Windows.UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule.CoreApplication_UnhandledErrorDetected(Object sender, $UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs e)
TestApp.ViewModel.LoginViewModel.OnLoginButtonClick() in F:\SVN\ TestApp\TestApp\ViewModel\LoginViewModel.cs:line 71
_$ILCT$.$ILT$ReflectionDynamicInvoke$.InvokeRetV(Object thisPtr, IntPtr methodToCall, ArgSetupState argSetupState, Boolean targetIsThisCall)
SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x68c058
SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x68bcb2
```

Nothing about NotImplementedException. In this case, this crashlog is useless for me, since it doesn't tell me what's the actual issue.

Should I configure something else?
This is the current config:

```
    HockeyClient.Current.Configure("<MY_HOCKEY_ID>",
        new TelemetryConfiguration { EnableDiagnostics = true })
        .SetExceptionDescriptionLoader((Exception ex) => "Exception HResult:" + ex.StackTrace);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Should I configure something else?

Please note that you need to upload symbol (*.pdb) files to HockeyApp in order to symbolicate crashes for your UWP application.

Since currently it seems your app has not been published in the Store, you could build side-loading symbols.

You may do the following steps for each of the platform (x86, x64, ARM):

1. In Visual Studio select checkbox Compile with .NET Native tool chain
2. Build application
3. Copy *.pdb files from \bin[Platform]\Release\ilc\ folder

And then you could upload them to Hockey app.

For more details, you can refer to **[How to upload symbols for UWP application](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-windows-and-windows-phone/how-to-upload-symbols-for-uwp-application)** .